# Cannot duplicate a simple login CSS effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a CSS beginner. For learning purpose, I was trying to copy the CSS effect of the login box from this website:
https://enichecommerce.freshbooks.com/

At the beginning I copy the code one DOM each time to understand the CSS impact. Later on, I just saved all the website (HTML, CSS, and JS) to my hard drive using Firefox "save page as" function, but when I open it, the visual effect of Login box is not what it looks from Internet.

Why could this happen? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem seems to come from the urls in the css file.  They are relative urls that firefox appears to be messing up on save:

```
.boxMain {
    background-image: url("/images/2ndSite/loginpage-bgtile.gif");
```

I'm not sure what effect you are talking about being missing, but this one causes the background of the login box to be grey instead of white.

Comment: I see... It's part of the reason. Thanks!